# iterations using if statement loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, iteration

I have a question that cannot use if else statements, or boolean.

```
    ans=input("enter input")
```

If the answer is `0<ans<999` then it prints "hi". However, I cannot use if statements. Another condition is that if ans is `>5000 and <6000` with an increment `of 5000 (10,000<11,000)` basically having a remainder of 5000 exists between each thousand then I need to print "hi".

I want to achieve both of these conditions,
 one condition is that ans is less than 999 and
 one that is greater than 5000 but less than 6000.

How can I achieve this without if statements??

Comment: I inputted in code so I could format the less than and greater than sorry about that :P

Comment: Why you cannot use the if statements ?

Comment: Are we doing your homework? You should at least post your attempt.

Comment: @bphi's solution with a list answers your question, but I'm really wondering why you're doing this. I can't even think of a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
ans = input("enter input")
print ('', 'hi')[int(0 < ans % 5000 < 999)]
```

The edge cases at 999, 1000, 5000, 5001, etc are a little more challenging

Here's an alternative with no booleans

```
ans = input("enter input")
print (([''] + ['hi'] * 999 + [''] * 4000) * (1 + (ans/5000)))[ans]
```

Again, I didn't check this for all edge cases

Comment: Something like this would work, but the OP doesn't want to use booleans too. And `0 < int(ans) % 5000 < 999` is a boolean.

Comment: @Unatiel Is there any way we can do this without boolean or conditionals ?

Comment: @Unatiel See the new even uglier alternative